# iOS new image type HEIC can't be used, must get JPEG

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap, cordova-plugin-camera

I am using

```
navigator.camera.getPicture
```

to get the picture from the camera roll on iOS.

If I add the option:

```
navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
```

it gives me a JPG which is great, but I can't get the geolocation EXIF information from it. To get the location I need to use:

```
navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
```

However that gives me a HEIC file. That cannot be used in an img tag or in any real way.

The end goal is to get the EXIF location information from the image as well as a usable JPG.

Comment: .......................

Comment: Cordova bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12613